# Derived Class using Parent Method

Tags: c#

Why can't i access the age method from either class A or B? I thought because it's a protected method, derived class instances should be able to use it?

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {



    }

    public static void Test(A test)
    {
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();

        Console.WriteLine(a.Age());
        Console.WriteLine(b.Age());
    }
}

public class A
{
    public virtual string Name { get { return "TestA"; } }
    protected string Age() { return "25";}
}

public class B : A
{

    public override string Name { get { return "TestB"; }  }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

---As suggested by Jon Skeet--

```
 public class B : A
 {

    public override string Name { get { return "TestB"; }  }
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public void Testing()
    {
        B a = new B();
        a.Age();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are accessing the function from class Program, so the protected modifier means you can't

Comment: Derived class instances are able to access the protected methods, but in this case you have instantiated the objects in a class which doesn't have to do anything with those classes. So, only public methods and variables can be accessed from there. If you want to make use of Age method using class B's instance, you can override it as public and do your implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Protected means it can be used from code in the derived classes - it doesn't mean it can be used "from the outside" when working with derived classes.

The `protected` modifier can be somewhat tricky, because even a derived class can only access the protected member through instances of its own class (or further derived classes).

So within the code of B, you could write:

```
A a = new A();
Console.WriteLine(a.Age()); // Invalid - not an instance of B
B b = new B();
Console.WriteLine(b.Age()); // Valid - an instance of B
A ba = b;
Console.WriteLine(ba.Age()); // Invalid
```

The last of these is invalid because even though at execution time it's accessing the member on an instance of `B`, the compiler only knows of `ba` as being of type `A`.

Here's the start of section 3.5.3 of the C# 5 specification, which may clarify things:

> When a `protected` instance member is accessed outside the program text of the class in which it is declared, and when a `protected internal` instance member is accessed outside the program text of the program in which it is declared, the access must take place within a class declaration that derives from the class in which it is declared. Furthermore, the access is required to take place *through* an instance of that derived class type or a class type constructed from it. This restriction prevents one derived class from accessing `protected` members of other derived classes, even when the members are inherited from the same base class.

Comment: Thank you Great Jon Skeet! I have updated my answer and just wanted to check if that's what you are saying and is the only option to access a protected member?

Comment: @Baahubali: Well yes, if you want access to a protected member, it has to follow those rules... although the `Testing()` method could call `Age()` without creating a new instance, as it's *in* an instance of `B`. (So that would be equivalent to `B.Age()`.)